# Can PRTG monitor IP traffic?

Tags: traffic, mrtg

We often use [MRTG For Windows](https://www.paessler.com/info/mrtg_for_windows) to monitor interface traffic.

Now there is an additional requirement: can I use MRTG to monitor IP traffic? If the `10.10.10.0/24` goes through the interface, can I monitor every IP's traffic?

---

**Edit-01**

I want to monitor the IP addresses who pass through my router. 
if my router have 5 ports for access the IN/OUT traffic.

[image]

I have several questions:

1. Can I use a server under Switch_1 with 159.1.1.4/24 to monitor all the IP addresses by access my Router?
2. need I install any tools in my Router?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your link actually refers to the [PRTG Network Monitor](https://www.paessler.com/prtg). PRTG is a commercial product from Paessler AG, whereas [*The Multi Router Traffic Grapher* MRTG](https://oss.oetiker.ch/mrtg/) is an open source project under GNU General Public License. Monitoring traffic based on IP address is possible with PRTG, but MRTG doesn't have network packet analyzing & sniffing. On the other hand, PRTG only works on Windows.

You could use PRTG for monitoring bandwidth via [Packet Sniffing](https://www.paessler.com/manuals/prtg/packet_sniffer_monitoring) or [xFlows](https://www.paessler.com/manuals/prtg/flow_monitoring). These monitors have [filter rules](https://www.paessler.com/manuals/prtg/xflow_packet_sniffer_filter_rules) for IP addresses and ports. While packet sniffing is the most flexible, it's also the heaviest.

> [Comparing](https://www.paessler.com/manuals/prtg/bandwidth_monitoring_comparison) the four bandwidth monitoring technologies that PRTG
>   provides (SNMP, Windows Management Instrumentation (WMI), xFlow, and
>   packet sniffing), packet sniffing creates the most CPU and network
>   load, so you should only use it in small to medium-sized networks, on
>   dedicated computers for larger networks, or for individual computers.

Other limitations on monitoring *every IP's traffic* might be:

- You should be able to see all the traffic. For this, the PRTG machine should be either routing the traffic or connected to a *monitoring port* on your switch.
- The PRTG [pricing](https://www.paessler.com/prtg/pricing): it's only free up to 100 sensors.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. I want to ask more, 1. how to understand the `sensors`? if there have 1,000 IP I want to be monitor, whether it means 1,000 sensors? 2.how to understand the `monitoring port`? whether it just means a port my monitor server can connect then access my router? or more function the monitoring port have?

Comment: I don't know how they exactly count the monitors. A monitoring port is a port on a (managed) switch that every packet from any port gets mirrored to.